# Attempt to read property "episode" on null

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-8, laravel-blade

The following code snippet is to collect and display the number of times of several videos.
But it shows the following error:

> Attempt to read property "episode" on null

from this line:

```
$course->time = $this->getCourseTime($course->episode->pluck('time'));
```

AdminController:

```
public function setCourseTime($episode)
{
    $course = $episode->course;
    $course->time = $this->getCourseTime($course->episode->pluck('time'));
    $course->save();
}


protected function getCourseTime($times)
{
    $timestamp = Carbon::parse('00:00:00');
    foreach ($times as $row)
    {
        $time = strlen($row) == 5 ? strtotime('00:' . $row) : strtotime($row);
        $timestamp->addSecond($time);
    }

    return $timestamp->format('H:i:s');
}
```

Model Course.php

```
public function episode()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Episode::class);
}
```

Model Episode.php

```
public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}
```

EpisodeController.php

```
public function store(EpisodeRequest $request)
{

    $episode = Episode::create($request->all());
    $this->setCourseTime($episode);

    return to_route('episode.index');
}
```

Comment: What is `$episode`?

Comment: Relationship with the model `Episode.php`

Comment: We don't know what `Episode.php` is either

Comment: The error means `$course` is null (hence why you can't read a property from it). We don't know why that is. Something is presumably wrong or missing, in the `$episode` object. Try to provide a [mre] of the issue, please. See also [ask].

Comment: What code should I write to identify this object?

Comment: How should we know? We don't know anything about your episode object, or where you want the data to come from to populate the course, or what.

Comment: Can I edit the post and give a general explanation?

Comment: Yes you can edit your post anytime you like. If it gives some context and some debugging information, plus code that shows how the episode object is supposed to populate the its course property, that would likely help.

Comment: You seem to have changed the error message. Which line of code exactly is throwing that error?

Comment: this line `$course->time = $this->getCourseTime($course->episode->pluck('time'));`

Comment: Ok so the problem is still that `$course` is null. Which means in turn that `$episode->course;` is null. Which means that `$episode` didn't set its `course` property. I'm assuming you called `setCourseTime` from the EpisodeController, so then it must mean that `$episode = Episode::create($request->all());` created an `$episode` object where the `course` property is not set. But you haven't shown us the code of `Episode::create`, so we can't go any further at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume on the `Episode` Model you mean to name the relationship `course` **not** `courses`, since it is a Belongs To (singular) relationship.

Currently, unless you have an attribute/accessor/relationship named `course` you will be getting back a `null` when trying to access that 'attribute'/property.

Additionally, when creating a new `Episode` model it isn't going to create the related record for you. After creation the related record doesn't exist so the relationship would not return a result.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when the object you have for you key is null. For ex: $course->episode, here you are reading property 'episode' on $course object. But when $course is null, then episode don't exist. So, make sure your $course is not printing null. You can check return print_r($course) to see if it's null & why.

Answer (score -2):

Use `dd` for `$course->episodes`, if is null use this: 
`$course = $episode->course->load('episodes');`

Comment: Error `Call to a member function load() on null`

Comment: Milwad the issue is that course is null, not episodes. Read the error message again

Comment: `setCourseTime` exists in which file?

Comment: I explained fully

Comment: You must write like this:
```
$course = $episode->courses;
```

Comment: @milwad Not working.

Comment: Check your relations!
You can use dd for see data